# monitoring cassandra with prometheus monitoring tool

Tags: cassandra, prometheus

My prometheus tool is on centos 7 machine and cassandra is on centos 6. I am trying to monitor cassandra JMX port 7199 with prometheus. I keep getting error with my yml file. Not sure why I am not able to connect to the centos 6 (cassandra machine) Is my YAML file wrong or does it have something to do with JMX port 7199?
here is my YAML file:

## my global config

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
   - job_name: cassandra
     static_configs:
       - targets: ['10.1.0.22:7199']
```

Here is my prometheus log:

```
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:30:53.92549611Z caller=main.go:215 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.0.0, branch=HEAD, revision=0a74f98628a0463dddc90528220c94de5032d1a0)" 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:30:53.925623847Z caller=main.go:216 build_context="(go=go1.9.2, user=root@615b82cb36b6, date=20171108-07:11:59)" 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:30:53.92566228Z caller=main.go:217 host_details="(Linux 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 20 20:32:50 UTC 2017 x86_64 localhost.localdomain (none))" 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:30:53.932807536Z caller=web.go:380 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:30:53.93303681Z caller=targetmanager.go:71 component="target manager" msg="Starting target manager..." 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:30:53.932905473Z caller=main.go:314 msg="Starting TSDB" 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:30:53.987468942Z caller=main.go:326 msg="TSDB started" 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:30:53.987582063Z caller=main.go:394 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=prometheus.yml 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:30:53.988366778Z caller=main.go:371 msg="Server is ready to receive requests."  
level=warn ts=2017-12-08T04:31:00.561007282Z caller=main.go:377 msg="Received SIGTERM, exiting gracefully..."
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:31:00.563191668Z caller=main.go:384 msg="See you next time!" 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:31:00.566231211Z caller=targetmanager.go:87 component="target manager" msg="Stopping target manager..." 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:31:00.567070099Z caller=targetmanager.go:99 component="target manager" msg="Target manager stopped" 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:31:00.567136027Z caller=manager.go:455 component="rule manager" msg="Stopping rule manager..." 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:31:00.567162215Z caller=manager.go:461 component="rule manager" msg="Rule manager stopped" 
level=info ts=2017-12-08T04:31:00.567186356Z caller=notifier.go:483 component=notifier msg="Stopping notification handler..."
```

If anyone has instruction on how to connect prometheus to cassandra , both being on two different machines, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with your config, prometheus received a `TERM` signal and terminated gracefully.

If you are not getting metrics, check whether `10.1.0.22:7199/metrics` loads and returns metrics. You can also check the prometheus server's `/targets` endpoint for scraping status.

If you're not getting anything on your cassandra server's `/metrics` endpoint, it could be because you did not configure the [cassandra prometheus exporter](https://github.com/nabto/cassandra-prometheus) properly.

Comment: Where should I install the jmx exporter? should it be on same machine as cassandra or the same machine as prometheus. My prometheus and cassandra are on different machines.

Comment: Its added to cassandra itself. Please read the linked page above for install, configuration, and use instructions.

Comment: ty. That helped. Now my prometheus is able to remote monitor cassandra.